# If/else statements not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I cannot figure out why if/else statements are not executing properly. The code only runs through the if(i===1) loop but thats it. I'm doing a simple exercise wherein I check the number submitted and see if the users gets hotter or colder to a preset number.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var checkNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        alert("Random number is" + checkNum);
        var i = 0;
        var scopedVal;
        var submitVal;
        var hotCheck = function (submitVal) {
            if(i === 1) {
                alert("try again");
                scopedVal = submitVal;
                alert("scopedVal is" + scopedVal);
            } else {
                if(abs(scopedVal - checkNum) > abs(submitVal - checkNum)) {
                    alert("Hotter");
                    scopedVal = submitVal;
                } else {
                    alert("colder");
                    scopedVal = submitVal;
                }
            }
        };
        $('.subm').on('click', function () {
            i++;
            alert(" i is" + i);
            alert("button pressed");
            submitVal = $(this).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.num').val();
            if(submitVal === checkNum) {
                alert("You got it");
            } else {
                hotCheck(submitVal);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    body {
        width: 900px;
        color: white;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #outsideContainer {
        width: 400px;
        color: grey;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outsideContainer">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="text" class="num">
            <br/>
        </form>
        <div id="buttonSubm">
            <button class="subm">Submit</button>
            <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm assuming this is a simple fix and it is driving me nuts.

Comment: Try == instead of ===. Also what kind of error are you getting in Firebug (or console, etc.) if any?

Comment: Are you trying to get a random number range in your `checkNum` variable? If so, you need to do it like this. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 1` (gives you a number between 1 and 7).

Comment: Where is `abs` defined?

Comment: Your HTML is missing a couple `</div>`

Comment: @Geroy290: `===` is perfectly acceptable in JavaScript, you might be mistaking JS for some other language.

Comment: This === means 'exactly matches'(case,datatype,etc.), where == is more forgiving and will match between data types, but performs more slowly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the "else" code as well as the "if" code remove the else statement:

```
    var hotCheck = function(submitVal){
        if(i===1){ 
            console.log("try again");
            scopedVal = submitVal;
            console.log("scopedVal is " + scopedVal);
        };
        if(Math.abs(scopedVal-checkNum)> Math.abs(submitVal - checkNum)){
            console.log("Hotter");
            scopedVal = submitVal;
        } else {
            console.log("colder");
            scopedVal = submitVal;
        };
    };
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/hHC88/

You also needed to change abs. to Math.abs

Comment: Thanks, the if code wasn't the problem but the Math.abs is what was causing this. Somehow I overlooked that simple error.

Comment: No problem, always check the console for errors :) If your question is answered please select as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The abs() method does not exist.  You're dealing with all integers so you can probably just remove it or fully reference it Math.abs()

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the

```
if( abs(scopedVal-checkNum)> abs(submitVal - checkNum)){
```

to

```
if( Math.abs(scopedVal-checkNum) > Math.abs(submitVal - checkNum)){
```

abs() is a method to Math.

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gaowei1972/Xv2Sq/)